# Spring JPA repository query is returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, repository

Spring JPA repository query is returning null but if I run the same query on database it returns the results. I couldn't find the reason why jpa query is returning null.

Repository Class:

```
public interface RelatorioContribuinteInadimplenteRepository extends  JpaRepository<RelatorioContribuinteInadimplenteView, String>{

  @Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 600)
  @Query(value = " SELECT EMPLOYEE_FORM_ID"
        + " FROM EMPLOYEE_FORM"
        + " WHERE FORM_TYPE_CD = ?1 ", nativeQuery = true)

List<RelatorioContribuinteInadimplenteView> findByFilters(String code);

  }
```

Entity class:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_FORM")
  public class RelatorioContribuinteInadimplenteView implements Serializable         {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name = "FORM_TYPE_CD")
   @Getter @Setter
   private String regiaoTributaria;

   @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_FORM_ID")
    @Getter @Setter
   private String ordem;



  }
```

Table in database is:

```
 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_FORM 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_FORM_ID" CHAR(12 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "FORM_TYPE_CD" CHAR(12 BYTE) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
       PRIMARY KEY ("TAX_FORM_ID")
       );
```

Comment: have you tried just sql query to the database? are you sure that the expected data exists?

Comment: What is the code you are using in the query? It has to be 12 characters long as you use a `CHAR(12) as a datatype. So you need te prefix is with spaces to make it 12 long. Else it will never match.

Comment: As I have mentioned, the sql returns the expected data in database. I am  using above entity for mapping the table fields

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you find only one column `SELECT EMPLOYEE_FORM_ID`, but attempt to fill in the whole entity `RelatorioContribuinteInadimplenteView`, then the framework gets lost because it does not know how to fill your entity.

Use this: `SELECT * FROM ...`